# Preload admob Native Template ad

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob

can anyone please help me.
I'm trying to preload the Native template Ads but i don't know if it's possible.
This is the code of it.

```
MobileAds.initialize(this);
AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
    .forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNativeAdLoaded(NativeAd nativeAd) {
            NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
              NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().withMainBackgroundColor(background).build();
            TemplateView template = findViewById(R.id.my_template);
            template.setStyles(styles);
            template.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
        }
     })
     .build();

adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

As you can see you need to specify the template on onNativeAdLoaded().